# Are Azure staging slots for dev and prod or prod only

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-deployment-slots

I’m confused on if the deployment slots in Azure function apps are meant to be used for only prod slots or is it okay to use for both dev and production. We currently have some Azure function apps that have 2 different versions. One for dev and one for prod. We'd like to utilize deployment slots to achieve the same thing, but aren't sure if that's their intended purpose or best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more of an Architecture decision.
You could use them either-ways, However as a best practice the deployment slots can be used in Production, It enables you to swap the slots when you feel it is well tested and ready for end-users to use the application. At any point in time, If you want to rollback, its easy to swap the slots to its earlier version.

For Production grade, Its better to use deployment slots as you see them fit., and have a separate application for Development environments.

Refer to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-slots) here for more details.